# Custom uitableviewcell not working in LazyTableImages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am using custom `UITableView` cell in my app and i had integrated LazyTableImages sample code to download image in tableview. I am using the below code in

```
- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        IconDownloader *iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
        if (iconDownloader != nil)
        {
            CustomTblViewCell *cell = (CustomTblViewCell *)[self.TblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView];

            // Display the newly loaded image
            cell.ImgViewUser.image = iconDownloader.appRecord.m_strImage;
        }

        // Remove the IconDownloader from the in progress list.
        // This will result in it being deallocated.
        [imageDownloadsInProgress removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
        [m_CtrlTblViewFacetoface reloadData ];
}
```

The above code is not loading any data but when i used the `UITableView` cell instead of Customcell then it is working, Any idea?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Be specific.

Comment: tableview not appearing full blank

Comment: check that are you really getting data in lazyLoading...

Comment: see my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121010/ios-how-to-update-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

simply there is a library I used it before and it worked well this library called " [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)" you can use it simply by a method:

```
[cell.ImgViewUser setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

and it cache images automatically and it support loading only from cache (if you need) and handle memory warning automatically .