# How to Download Images in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

How to download Images in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method?

I have Code as Below

```
Cell_ClubOffer *cell = [tableFavouriteDealsAndClubs dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell_ClubOffer alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        if (indexPath.section < [array_favouriteClubs count]){

            //show clubs here

            ClubDAO *ob = (ClubDAO*)[array_favouriteClubs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            NSLog(@"MY IMAGE URL IS %@", ob.logopath); //is Logo Path

           //Use other ob values on Cell and return it


           return cell;


        }else{

            //show deals here

            int section = (indexPath.section-[array_favouriteClubs count]);

            NSLog(@"SECTION IS %d", (indexPath.section-[array_favouriteClubs count]));

            NSLog(@"COUNT IS OBJECT IS %d", [array_favouriteDeals count]);


            DealsDAO *ob = (DealsDAO*)[array_favouriteDeals objectAtIndex: section];
            NSLog(@"MY IMAGE URL IS %@", ob.logopath); //is Logo Path

           //Use other ob values on Cell and return it

           return cell;

     }
```

Now, here I have two Arrays,

***array_favouriteDeals***
***array_favouriteClubs***

SO, there are two Arrays contains, different objects, as indexOfFirst ends, I simply use ***(indexPath.section-[array_favouriteClubs count]);*** as next Index.

How how to download images for such scenario?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121010/ios-how-to-update-uitableviewcell

Comment: Not suitable, because How it will load on same Image, i have Customcell.ImageView, which are different for each section ???

Comment: Use SDWebImage to load and download Image

Comment: I have two arrays, these example suits when all the cell coming from same sort of index

Comment: use SDWebImage or something like NSData* imageData = [NSData dataFromURL:imageURL]; put that in it's own method and do [self performSelectorinBackground@selector(selector)];